# Why does Empathy ask for permission to access my remote accounts?

Tags: empathy

In order to let Empathy work, Ubuntu asks permission to collect information about me. Why is it that when I choose that I do not want Ubuntu to collect information about me, Empathy does not work?

In Fedora and OpenSUSE I do not have this problem!

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything collecting information about you, empathy uses online accounts integration to provide the credentials necessary to login to those services.  It isn't really different than with the earlier versions of empathy where you gave empathy your login information directly.  Now when you setup the account, you can also choose to let other applications use the same credentials.  For example, if you add your google account, you can allow empathy and evolution to use it for IM and email.

The account information you add stays on your local system, and not shared elsewhere.